# newb: typo3 access uploaded images in typoscript

Tags: image, typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to do something like in [this Tutorial](http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/cool-stuff-typoscript/simple-image-gallery-from-media-field.html), a very basic gallery.
In the example of the Tut they load images from uploads/media/ like so

```
page.10.marks.PROJECTTHUMBNAIL = IMG_RESOURCE
page.10.marks.PROJECTTHUMBNAIL {
  stdWrap.wrap = <img src="|" />
  file {
    import = uploads/media/
    import.data = levelmedia: -1,slide  
    import.listNum = 0      
  }
}
```

but now I want to load pictures that have been uploaded in an image-cObject.

This is an embarrassing question but I've been trying to figure this out for two days and I can't seem to get it right -.- I'm sure there are lots of answers out there... I just don't know the magic words to put into google to FIND them T-T

I tried very basic stuff like just doing the same as above but with a different path, I rummaged through the `TSRef` of `IMAGE` and `IMG_RESOURCE`, tried fiddling with `CONTENT`, and tried to adapt the `tt_content.image.20 = USER` (?? O.o) description in the typoscript object-browser... but all to no avail, as I know so little what I'm doing -.-

Any nudge in the right direction would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: **Do you mean you want to load images that are saved as Image content elements on a page?** `cObjects` (as defined in Typoscript) are just ways of rendering content, they don't store any information. Just as in your example: the file is physically stored in *uploads/media/* folder, reference to this file is in the database field *media* which is in the *pages* table, and `IMG_RESOURCE` is just a way you tell TYPO3 what to do with it.

Comment: @cascaval Thank you for your comment! Yes, I mean I want to load images that are saved as Image content elements, exactly. Sorry if that was unclear. Thank you for clearing up what cObjects are. I really had quite a fuzzy grasp. D'oh. -.-'

Comment: [arg, wanted to make a new line, not post the comment] @casaval: However if I replace the line 'import = uploads/media/' with 'import = uploads/pics/' I get image-tags with empty src. [Except if I have the same pictures both in uploads/media/ and in uploads/pics/ then they get displayed with src-path uploads/pics/; I'm guessing this is because of the "slide"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the content elements using the `CONTENT` cObject and set how the content shall be rendered. This will load Image content elements on the given page regardless of what column they are in:

```
page.10.marks.PROJECTTHUMBNAIL = CONTENT
page.10.marks.PROJECTTHUMBNAIL {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    where = CType = 'image' AND image != ''
    orderBy = sorting ASC
  }
  renderObj = IMAGE
  renderObj {
    file {
      import = uploads/pics/
      import.field = image
      import.listNum = 0
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: The `renderObj` is just my example and it renders **only the first image** of the Image element. You can set the rendering as you please, e.g. set the file to be `GIFBUILDER` which would allow you to resize the image. You can also tweak the select to load content elements with more refined conditions.

Comment: Yess! :D :D Thank you so much! It works like a charm... And I think that maybe I'm starting to grasp it now... now I'll have a look at the TSRef and see if I can figure out my other options to tweak it :)